# Scheduling a Python script to run every 1 hr (details in description)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

My question is simple. I have a Python script that pulls data from an API that has a limit of only 150 requests per hour (here 150 dates of data). I have a total of 6 chunks (`6 * 150`) to pull. So I am trying to schedule this script so it runs every 1 hour for 150 dates and sleeps for 1 hr.

How do I do it?

Comment: I have heard something about crontab. Maybe that will get your task done :)

Comment: Something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html)?

Comment: Cron will be your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

#### For MacOs:

check out crontab:

run `crontab -e` in the terminal and
crontab will open a terminal editor, type:

`* 1 * * * python3 ~/full/path/to/script.py`

save it and it should work.

for more information about crontab [check this](https://www.geekbitzone.com/posts/macos/crontab/macos-schedule-tasks-with-crontab/)

---

#### For Windows:

Checkout Task Scheduler-

Press `Win+R` and type in `taskschd.msc`

Then click `Create Task`

Set a trigger for every 1 hour:

[image]

And set an action to run the script:

[image]

This should do the job

Comment: crontab is available for Linux too :)